# Links in iframe not opening inside visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: iframe, salesforce, visualforce, sapui5, hana

I have to show a webportal developed in openui5 hana inside iframe in visualforce.But it is not showing up the page inside iframe.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help, but try adding the webportal URL in remote site settings under setup.